# I would like to develop metro app right now. What should I do?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to develop real metro apps on Windows 7 or should I download the beta of Windows 8? What are the libraries, packages, or software I need to install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 8 Developer Preview is a Windows 8 Image with Visual Studio 11 preinstalled. This will have everything you need to get started. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516

I don't think you'll be able to develop a metro app on windows 7

Comment: Download the 64 bits versión, the 32 bits version doesn't  have the dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

You need Windows 8. As Prescott said, Windows 8 Developer Preview has a version with developer tools (including VS 11 Developer Preview). I run Windows 8 on a VM with 1.5GB RAM, and it works great, even though the stated minimum is 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot develop Metro apps in Windows 7. Everything you need to develop is at [www.buildwindows.com](http://www.buildwindows.com)
There you can get the OS, tools,  samples, documentation, forums, etc.